# Angular - split inside an expression

Tags: angularjs, split

I have some predefined classes that needs to be assigned dynamically.

product name will be "most played" or "new deck"

i have classes in name of "most" and "new"

```
<div class="{{i.productName}}"></div>
```

How to split inside an expression here?

Below lines doesn't serve the need.

```
<div class="{{i.productName.split(" ")[0]}}"></div>
```

Comment: Try it as: i.productName.split(' ')[0] since you're inside double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to make a filter:

```
app.filter('firstWord', function() {
    return function(str) {
        return str.split(" ")[0];
    };
});
```

Use it as:

```
<div class="{{ i.productName|firstWord }}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It Works. split belongs to string functions and i added tostring to make the object to primitive data type.

```
<div class="{{i.productName.toString().split(" ")[0]}}"></div>
```